# How to modify just one element of a tuple without rewriting it completely?

Tags: haskell, tuples, variable-assignment

[How to modify just one field of a record without rewriting it completely?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55837998/how-to-modify-just-one-field-of-a-record-without-rewriting-it-completely)

Here I learned a helpful Haskell syntax to modify an element of a record without rewriting it completely:

```
oldrecord { somefield = newvalue }
```

Is something similar possible with tuples?

```
type ABigTuple = (Int, Int, Double, Int, String)

aBigTuple :: ABigTuple
aBigTuple = (5, 6, 3.2, 10, "asdf") 

anotherBigTuple = -- replace the 3rd elt of the prev tuple with 5.5 i/o 3.2
```

Is this possible in a manner similar to records, or do I have to rewrite the whole tuple?

Comment: The ‘best’ way is to using tuples and use a record instead. This helps with understanding what your type represents, too.

Comment: @AJFarmar I think you accidentally a word. "stop using tuples" perhaps?

Comment: @moonGoose I'm rationing my words. They don't grow on trees you know!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I assume by "rewriting the whole tuple" you mean something like,

```
(\(a,b,_,d,e) -> (a,b,3.2,d,e))
```

There are [lenses](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.17.1/docs/Control-Lens-Tuple.html) for tuples, the link has plenty of examples.

```
_3 .~ (3.2 :: Double)
```